# Group rows in a 2d array by one column and sum another column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

So I have 2d array, with some arrays inside. indexes are all same in arrays: "id" and "cost". On same "id" values I want to sum "number" values.
Here's my 2d array:

```
$array = array (
    array ('id' => 2, 'cost' => 300),
    array ('id' => 1, 'cost' => 200),
    array ('id' => 2, 'cost' => 100),
);
```

I've made some code, but it get's not exactly what i want.

```
$result = array ();
foreach($array as $item){
  if (isset($result[$item['id']])){
      $result[$item['id']] += $item['cost'];
  }else{
      $result[$item['id']] = $item['cost'];
  }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Will show me this:

```
array (size=2)
2 => int 400
1 => int 200
```

I want it to show me like this:

```
array (size=2)
 0 => 
  array (size=2)
  'id' => int 2
  'cost' => int 400
 1 => 
  array (size=2)
  'id' => int 1
  'cost' => int 200
```

Comment: If your data comes from mysql it's better to `SUM` and `GROUP BY` there.

Comment: Interesting offer, will try :)

Comment: you need unset current array sum and recreate new array.

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate it as an array if the key does not exist. Add the `cost` if it already exist.

```
$array = array (
    array ('id' => 2, 'cost' => 300),
    array ('id' => 1, 'cost' => 200),
    array ('id' => 2, 'cost' => 100),
);

$result = array ();
foreach($array as $item){
    if (isset($result[$item['id']])){
            //Add the cost
            $result[$item['id']]["cost"] += $item['cost'];
    } else {
            //Init as array
            $result[$item['id']] = array( "id" => $item['id'], "cost" => $item['cost'] );
    }
}
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [cost] => 400
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [cost] => 200
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` and `array_values` for the desired result

```
$array = array (
        array ('id' => 2, 'cost' => 300),
        array ('id' => 1, 'cost' => 200),
        array ('id' => 2, 'cost' => 100),
);
$res = [];
foreach($array as $key => $value){

  array_key_exists($value['id'], $res) ? (
    $res[$value['id']]['cost'] += $value['cost']
  )
  :
  (
    $res[$value['id']] = [
        'id' => $value['id'],
        'cost' => $value['cost']
    ]
  );

}
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_values($res));
```

Result

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [cost] => 400
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [cost] => 200
    )

)
```

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/4eYKE)

Answer (score 0):

If you only push reference variables into the result array when a unique id is encountered, you won't need to call `array_values()` to reindex the result after looping.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/X8ROZ))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($ref[$row['id']])) {
        $ref[$row['id']] = $row;
        $result[] = &$ref[$row['id']];
    } else {
        $ref[$row['id']]['cost'] += $row['cost'];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```