# Group an array of objects by one column and sum another column within each group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

After merging two arrays of objects, I get an array structured like this. I would like to group objects with the same ID and add to their quantity

```
[
    {
        id  :   1
        nome    :   T.SHIRT
        quantita    :   2
    
    }, 
    {
        id  :   2
        nome    :   Sweatshirt
        quantita    :   4
    
    },
  {
        id  :   1
        nome    :   T.SHIRT
        quantita    :   4
    
    }
]
```

I would like to get an array like this.

```
[
    {
        id  :   1
        nome    :   T.SHIRT
        quantita    :   6
    
    }, 
  {
        id  :   2
        nome    :   Sweatshirt
        quantita    :   4
    
    },
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: In the same loop as you've created the first structured array, *hint* use the id of the product as the (array)key and test with `isset`

Comment: Earlier asked question: [Group rows in a 2d array by one column and sum another column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56172554/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following logic might help you on your way: `$store` will contain the restructured array with cumulative 'quantita' per 'id'.

```
<?php
$arr = [
    (object)['id' => 1, 'nome' => 'T.SHIRT', 'quantita' => 2,],
    (object)['id' => 2, 'nome' => 'Sweatshirt', 'quantita' => 4,],
    (object)['id' => 1, 'nome' => 'T.SHIRT', 'quantita' => 4,],
];

$store = [];
foreach($arr as $record) {
    if(isset($store[$record->id])) {
        $store[$record->id]->quantita += $record->quantita;
    } else $store[$record->id] = $record;
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/b94aU)